# Reuse temp directory in DITA-OT?

Tags: dita, dita-ot

While using DITA OT 2.2.1, I usually have to generate documents in several different output formats. For example, I have to generate output for the same ditamap in pdf2, htmlhelp, and xhtml formats.

Question: Is it possible to reduce the generation time of the documents by "reusing" the temp directory? For example, the generation of the same document in pdf2 and xhtml could reuse the same temp directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that does not work (because the temporary files are different). You can keep the `temp` directories by setting the parameter `clean.temp` to `no` and compare those directories by yourself, if you like.

If you really want to save publication time, you should take a look at the Gradle plugin [dita-ot-gradle](https://github.com/eerohele/dita-ot-gradle), developed by Eero Helenius. Gradle is a build management tool like Apache Ant (the DITA-OT uses Ant). You can find a tutorial here: [eerohele.github.io/dita-ot-gradle/build](http://eerohele.github.io/dita-ot-gradle/build/).

If you use this plugin, you save the needed time for deploying a new Java Virtual Machine (JVM), because the JVM is reused (not the temp dir).